# Python OpenCV - apply colored mask to image

Tags: python, opencv

I got the following things:

- an Image read with OpenCV (numpy array)
- a binary mask of the same size as the image
- a color string like `'red'`,`'blue'`, etc

**Q**: how do i color the mask before i add it to the image?
explicitly: how do i add color channels to a binary mask given a color string

I know how to add the mask (for example with `cv2.addWeighted(mask,alpha,image,1-alpha,0,image)` ) , but i dont know how to convert the binary mask to color space with a simple color 'string' as input. I know this works in PIL with `rgb = PIL.ImageColor.getrgb(color)`, but i dont know how to do this with OpenCV!

**EDIT**:
i managed to get the colors in channel tuples (0,0,0) and currently my workaround is:

```
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
mask[np.where((mask == [1,1,1]).all(axis = 2))] = color
cv2.addWeighted(mask,alpha,image,1-alpha,0,image)
```

but the problem is, now the image is greyscale with a colored map...
So the first line needs to be exchanged

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simpler and more native approach. What is a color filter if not a uniform shift you apply on one of your channels? I generally just use [np.power](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.power.html). Provided that **img** is a 3D RGB matrix of your image:

```
img = np.power(img,[1.5, 1.0, 1.0]) # shift the reds
img = np.power(img,[1.0, 1.5, 1.0]) # shift the greens
img = np.power(img,[1.2, 1.2, 1.0]) # orange type? (I suck at color mixing, you'll find out the one you need to shift) (since all your colors are made from a combination of these three basic ones)
```

I just stopped using openCV and PIL (which is deprecated, by the way, have a look at [skimage](http://scikit-image.org/)) when I discovered this trick

To apply your filter only on the masked section, you could do this:

```
mask =  numpy.expand_dims(mask, 2) 
mask = numpy.repeat(mask, 3, axis=2) # give the mask the same shape as your image
colors = {"red": [0.1,0.,0.], "blue": [0.,0.,0.1]} # a dictionary for your colors, experiment with the values
colored_mask = numpy.multiply(mask, colors["red"])  # broadcast multiplication (thanks to the multiplication by 0, you'll end up with values different from 0 only on the relevant channels and the right regions)
img = img+colored_mask # element-wise sum (sinc img and mask have the same shape)
```

Comment: So how would look the whole code for multiplying the colored binary mask to the image?

Comment: this is the thing: you don't need to add your mask anymore since you are applying changes directly on your images. What would count as a mask would be the [v,v,v] you pass as an argument

Comment: I would not. I merely gave a workaround to achieve what you are looking for without using complex functions from a complex library. It involves changing slightly the way you look at your problem and thus your code. If you want to use Open CV at **any cost** and not change a line of your code nor try what I just posted, my solution is not the one you are looking for

Comment: I would like to try your solution, the thing is that i just do not understand how to apply your idea.

I got three things: an image (3D RGB array), a mask (2D Binary) and a color (a 3 channel tuple).

Starting from this, how do i apply your code?

Comment: ah, ok, I just understand what you're trying to do. The filter you want to apply is not uniform but only on the "masked parts", right? I edit my answer

Comment: Hm i understand what you mean to do but that does not have the correct outcome / does not work. Still sticking to my solution.

Go try your solution with an image and an binary mask, it has no effect.

Comment: Well, it works for me. It's ugly (needs tuning) but it works. Two questions. First (sorry for this one), did you just copy paste {"red": [0.1,0.,0.], "blue": [0.,0.,0.1], etc} or did you think to remove the etc. Second, what kind of values do you have 0 <-> 1 or 0 <-> 255 (my solution works for the first one, with floats)

Comment: first: no, second: my mask is binary = 0,1

I dont know how and with which input you test, but for me if i apply your operations to the image and display it afterwards it does not do anything.